# Java order by priority list

Tags: java, comparator

Given a list of objects (`List<MyClass>` objects).

```
class MyClass {
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

And a list with names:

1. name1
2. name2
3. name3

Whats a nice way to write a comparator to use the list of names as a priority list and if a priority doesnt exist for a name use alphabetic ordering?

Comment: Will performance be an issue because there are many names in the list?

Comment: What is supposed to happend if one name is on the list but not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the strings into an array and loop through it to see which one you encounter first.

```
public class NameComparator implements Comparator {

  static private [] String strNames = {"Ken", "Alisia", "Ben"};

  public int compare(MyClass objX, MyClass objY) {
    String x = objX.Name;
    String y = objY.Name;
    String strCurrentName;

    if(x.equals(y)) {
      return 0;
    }

    for(strCurrentName: strNames) {
      if(strCurrentName.equals(x)) {
        return 1;
      }
      if(strCurrentName.equals(y)) {
        return -1;
      }
    }
    return x.compareTo(y);
  }

}
```

Sorting with this comparator would give you, for instance, "Ken", "Alicia", "Michelle" and "Nancy".

If speed is an issue you could put the names in a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead of an array. The code would then be quite different, I can give you an example if you are interested.

Comment: I just modified the code so it works when both objects have the same name.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, that you use the [`java.util.Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) method, and provide a custom comparator.

```java
// Define a new static comparator attribute for your class
public static Comparator<MyClass> MY_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) {
         return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);        // or whatever logic
    }
};

//Then just call this to sort when you need it
List<MyClass> myList;  // initialised somewhere
Collections.sort(myList, MY_COMPARATOR);
```

If you're using java 8+, then the code to create the comparator is even shorter:

```java
public static Comparator<MyClass> MY_COMPARATOR = (o1, o2) -> o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
```